# Passing arguments whilst multi threading in python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I recently learned that whilst using the threading library in python I cannot run my functions simultaneously.

I was wondering how I could run 3 functions at the same time.

Example:
Function 1: constantly sends data from a queue dictionary to a server as json.
Function 2: runs and updates the queue dictionary.
Function 3: monitors the computer cpu.

I can't seem to find any good guide or ways to implement this in python whereas in C# it's pretty simple.

Would appreciate some help (If someone has an example that would be amazing!).

Thank you!

Comment: I would make the queue external to `python ` (e.g. `RabbitMQ`, `ZeroMQ`) and have 3 independent python processes that can access it

Comment: From your question, you're looking  for [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) rather than `multithreading` (especially because of the [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock))

Comment: Read about [17.2.2.10. Listeners and Clients Examples](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.connection)